# Calculating the height of elements in Bootstrap for vertical alignment

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am newbie in Bootstrap & HTML.

In my HTML I have a container and a row with 3 columns inside. In my situation, the title of the last section is way longer than others and needs to be displayed in 2 lines.

Because of this, the text of this section is in lower position than it is in other sections.

**My question:** Is it possible to make all of these texts after headers to be vertically in the same position?

**HTML Code example:**

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
            <h2 class="section-heading">MAIN_TITLE</h2>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row text-center">

        <div class="col-md-3">
            <span class="fa-stack fa-4x">
                <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x text-primary"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-search fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
            </span>

            <h4 class="service-heading">TITLE_1</h4>
            <div class="text-muted eqHeight"> TEXT_1</div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3">
            <span class="fa-stack fa-4x">
                <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x text-primary"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-search fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
            </span>

            <h4 class="service-heading">TITLE_2</h4>
            <div class="text-muted eqHeight"> TEXT_2</div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3">
            <span class="fa-stack fa-4x">
                <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x text-primary"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-search fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
            </span>

            <h4 class="service-heading">TITLE_3</h4>
            <div class="text-muted eqHeight"> TEXT_3</div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3">
            <span class="fa-stack fa-4x">
                <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x text-primary"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-search fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
            </span>

            <h4 class="service-heading">TITLE_TITLE_TITLE_TITLE_TITLE_TITLE_TITLE_TITLE_TITLE_TITLE_TITLE_TITLE_TITLE_TITLE_TITLE_TITLE_TITLE_4</h4>
            <div class="text-muted eqHeight"> TEXT_4</div>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

This is how it looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

include jQuery and just write javascript for finding and setting the height of bigger one.

```
function max-height(){
    var height=0;
    var mHeight=0;
    $('.service-heading').each(function(){
        height = $(this).height();
        if(height>mHeight)
           mHeight = height;
    });
    $('.service-heading').height(mHeight);
    height=0;
    mHeight=0;
}
```

then call this function on ready() and resize()

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {max-height();});
 $( window ).resize(function() {max-height();});
```

Comment: When this `resize` function is called?

Comment: resize() will trigger when a window re-sizing happens. While re-sizing the window, there is chance for increase the height.

Answer (score 0):

in your code, text is aligned to center. i have removed it. check comment. then in the long text of title_title_title..so on, i have provided a space which encodes as newline character. 
In the column setup, you have provided 'col-md-3' for three time, which makes it three-fourth of the width. so changed it to " col-md-3 , col-md-3 , col-md-6".

check out this.

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
            <h2 class="section-heading">MAIN_TITLE</h2>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row ">  // removed text-center

        <div class="col-md-3">
            <span class="fa-stack fa-4x">
                <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x text-primary"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-search fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
            </span>

            <h4 class="service-heading">TITLE_1</h4>
            <div class="text-muted"> TEXT_1</div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3">
            <span class="fa-stack fa-4x">
                <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x text-primary"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-search fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
            </span>

            <h4 class="service-heading">TITLE_2</h4>
            <div class="text-muted"> TEXT_2</div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6"> // here col-md-3 changed to col-md-6
            <span class="fa-stack fa-4x">
                <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x text-primary"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-search fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
            </span>

            <h4 class="service-heading">TITLE_TITLE_TITLE_TITLE_TITLE_TITLE_TITLE _TITLE_TITLE_TITLE_TITLE_ TITLE_TITLE_TITLE_TITLE_TITLE_TITLE_3</h4> // here provided with a space.
            <div class="text-muted"> TEXT_3</div>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: You should try to explain the issue for him/her, not only providing the code to solve the issue in this case when he/she is new to all this.

Comment: Yea, but my problem isn't X position. My problem is Y position of the text

Answer (score 0):

**Changed answer:** Now that I get what you're asking here, I would recommend using [**eqHeight** library (jQuery)](https://github.com/jsliang/eqHeight.coffee/). It works like a charm with Bootstrap and what it does is that it automatically calculates the height of the tallest element and adjusts the height of others to same.

In this case you could do the following:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-4">
     <i class="service-heading eqHeight">Content here</i>
     <i>More content here!</i>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-4">
     <i class="service-heading eqHeight">Content here</i>
     <i>More content here!</i>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-4">
     <i class="service-heading eqHeight">Content here</i>
     <i>More content here!</i>
   </div>
</div>
```

The point is to make the eqHeight library point to the `.eqHeight` class and make it calculate the upper elements (in this case `.service-heading` classes) to be the same height.

This might require an additional CSS, but shouldn't be more than just `height` and `max-height` properties.

Vertical positioning is a slight problem with responsive design. Another solution for this would be of making an additional row below the existing one and setting the same cols in there, but that of course doesn't work when the site breaks up for mobile.

Comment: But my problem is Y position for text.

Comment: I have added an image to explain my problem better.

Comment: Updated my answer. I don't think there is any suggested CSS-styles or anything that would help ya in this case. Sure you could go for `min-height` property and adjust the `.text-primary` height with it, but the way it behaves in mobile is never guaranteed.

Comment: And I still kept the corrected column setup. One row should always have a total of **12**, if you want to adjust that, you should use the `.col-md-offset-1` class for pushing it forward, though if you use `.col-md-3` just three times, you should make use for **3** more column spaces to make the layout work as it is supposed. This might just cause issues later on, good to get it done right from the beginning.

Comment: I have added **eqHeight** library to the project, included file, but when the line `$(".container").eqHeight(".eqHeight");` is executed, the height is still not correct...

Comment: Does it change the height at all when it executes? If it does and it's still incorrect, you should see if your element has padding or margin, that may interfere with eqHeight and cause it to calculate the wrong height value.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93455/discussion-between-prodexorite-and-tom-kortney).